# Does importing the same library repeatedly impact performance?

Tags: javascript

I'm importing a library from a CDN in `main.js`:

```
import * as foo from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/foo";
```

However, that same library is also used in all other modules, `a.js`, `b.js` etc... Thus, in all of them, I'm repeating the `import`.

Does the browser sends a request to the CDN for every import, impacting performance? Or does the browser imports the library just once, and keeps it in memory for the `import` in the other modules?

---

<sup>PS: This could be a XY problem... my *real* original question was how to share a single import between several modules. I found solutions such as creating a global (`window.foo = foo`), but they seemed a bit hacky.</sup>

Comment: Try it out. Create a example where you have a bunch of imports. Then load the page and view the network tab. How often is a HTTP request to your module performed?

Comment: @Marc thanks, the test was clear, there are not additional requests. Can you turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said from me in the comments, and asked from op:

You can test that very simple by your own.
Create a webpage with a bunch of imports to the same library/module.

Open the developer tools and view the network tab.
How many http requests are done to the the lib/url you are importing?

**TL;DR: There are no additional requests for each import statement.**